# Will an IPA beer work properly for beer bread?

Tags: baking, bread, dough, beer

1. Is there any reason an **IPA** beer would be bad or not work for a beer bread dough?
2. Does it take longer, the same or short than a typical beer bread to rise?

Comment: You should probably post the beer bread recipe you intend to make. Some rely on the yeast in the beer (which must have not been pasteurised) but most just use it for flavour

Comment: ... And I'd prefer to use one with a bit more malt

Comment: No specific recipe, just shooting in the dark. Curious what would happen if I make a typical beer bread like I've had in the past but with an IPA instead. I'm worried most of the flavour.

Comment: @ChrisH, if it's an American recipe they'd be sure to say if an unpasteurized beer is needed, since despite the rise of microbreweries, the vast majority of beer sold here is still mass-produced lager.

Comment: @ThePhoton I expect the same would be true here (UK), but most of the reading I've done about beer bread has been in the context of homebrew. Unless a country is explicitly stated in the question I assume nothing about nationality

Answer (score 6):

IPA, especially these days, tends to have high bitterness...40 - 60 IBUs in general...often much higher.  Your biggest issue would be whether or not the bitterness would significantly influence the flavor or your bread. As far as the rise, as is mentioned in the comments above, active yeast in the beer may or may not be a factor.  You could always add some yeast to the recipe.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but normally wouldn't all the yeast be dead by the time the beer enters the bottle? Unless it is bottle conditioned (which is rarely found in beer).

Comment: @soup4life Actually, beer with active yeast is not at all rare.

Comment: perhaps it is more rare here in Ontario. I am avid beer drinking of whatever LCBO gets and there aren't many that I've found to be bottle conditioned. More craft brewers are doing it though.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely! I am an avid user of IPA's in my bread. I even make a sourdough starter with them. In my opinion, the more bitter/difficult to drink, the better it is for bread! Baking reduces those unpalatable flavour compounds so that they leave an aroma and flavour that is present but certainly palatable.

If you're using beer it's because you want your bread to taste like beer. Pale lagers don't do much for bread, if you want a flavour heavy and clearly beer bread, use them IPA's! I recommend trying stouts too.

I will substitute beer for liquid whenever I feel like and have never been disappointed by the results!
It hasn't affected leavening whatsoever, and it gives the bread colour, flavour and aroma! All the things you want from bread.

Go wild, I say! Experiment!
It'll please you.